# How to load a theme's clear.css before system.css and other module stylesheets?

Tags: css, drupal

So, I'd like to use a CSS reset (such as http://bit.ly/gd2hQX) as part of a theme I'm assembling. This will help me avoid assorted headaches with user agent defaults.

I dutifully mention clear.css in mytheme.theme, and turn on Drupal's CSS optimization so it will get loaded into the CSS cache file that becomes part of `$scripts` in `page.tpl.php`.

But, Drupal loads all the theme stylesheets *after* core stylesheets, so this ends up overriding many of the paddings, margins, etc on admin pages such as `admin/build/modules/list`. This is a pain.

I know I can manually add a `<link rel="stylesheet">` before `$scripts` in `page.tpl.php`, but then I don't get the full benefits of the CSS optimization.

Is there a way to have certain stylesheets load before core and module stylesheets? Ideally this could happen on the theme level, but I would be interested in alternative methods if that isn't possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four Kitchens has a [blog post on Promiscuous stylesheets in Drupal 7](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2010/11/12/promiscuous-stylesheets-drupal-7) that briefly discusses how to accomplish this in Drupal 6. It then points to the [ninesixty_css_reorder function](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/themes/ninesixty/template.php?revision=1.1.2.3&view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6--1-0) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way using D6. Using D7 you can implement hook_css_alter().

You have then <strike>3</strike> 4 possible solutions:

1. Implement only the resets you need into your clear.css
2. Patch core to include yours before
3. include yourself into the page.tpl.php, don't forget to use:

   < ?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/my/file.css'; ?>
4. Use your clear.css then rewrite what you erased with

The 3rd solution will make your file not being aggregated, but I doubt that using D6 you have any other solution.

The 1st one is the best (proper, cleaner, considering the framework), the 2nd is the ugliest, please, never patch core, you will make your life being hell! The 3rd will work but won't aggregate.

EDIT: Drupal makes life of theme developer really hard because of core and module arbitrary included CSS files, you are always forced to do proper CSS overrides to clear/reset what you need to.

Really, use the first solution or the 4th. I do the 4th myself, clear all, reset all, then rewrite all what you need. Core CSS files are not mandatory, really, and on most site you have quite nothing to rewrite.

Don't forget that in most case, you should use a different theme for admin and admin/* path that will at least release you of the fact you would then have to rewrite the full admin CSS specific theming.